# CentOS - How to install haproxy

Tags: centos, installation, haproxy

I have no experience with Linux. 
I want to install the [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/).
Where should I place the file for installation?

My position is at the root server.
/root

Can I use the following procedure?

```
wget http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/src/haproxy-1.4.20.tar.gz
gunzip haproxy-1.4.20.tar.gz
tar -xf haproxy-1.4.20.tar
cd haproxy-1.4.20
./configure
make
make install
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, but you probably shouldn't.  [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) has [haproxy packages](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/haproxy.html), and you'd be far more effective using those instead of trying to make your own build.

Comment: How can I install this package?

Comment: @Jenan: enable epel http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-centos-linux-enable-epel-repo/ then `yum install haproxy`

Comment: This error: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.dBrmAL: not an rpm package (or package manifest):

Comment: @Jenan: Questions go in questions, not comments.

Comment: More up-to-date instructions (i.e., not CentOS5 specific) on activating EPEL are available on http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories somewhere down the page.  Just search for EPEL, and you'll have links to the RPMs to install.